# mod_security : affordable rule sets

Tags: mod-security

I'm looking for practical advice on the OWASP rule set for mod_security. I've heard it has many false positives, and wondering if people have successfully applied it?

I can't afford the TrustWave and my first few interactions with Atomicorps GotRoot rules has not been positive so I'm exiting my options.

Are there any other rule set providers?

Comment: Have you tried the [Comodo rule set](https://waf.comodo.com/)? An alternative approach would be to use Cloudflare's security, there is a free version which is pretty good.

Comment: Looks awesome! Had not heard of that. Cheers. Have you experience with them compared to other rule sets?

Comment: Sorry, I've only dealt with them in the past from some other of their products. They were OK to deal with. Did you see my updated comment re Cloudflare?

Comment: Yeah I did (re cloudflare) I have thought about it, but when I trailed it, my DNS was having some issues working properly and the caching they use also messed with some code i was running

Comment: Yes, you do need to be a bit conservative about the code caching. However, the security features are excellent. Just turn off the code caching if you don't want it. Use them & mod_security if you want!

Comment: Yes, I must admit it is tempting....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I've not used them myself, another ruleset is produced by Comodo. I've used a number of their products over the years and they seem OK to deal with.

In addition, you can use the free tier of Cloudflare to add security to your website. I've been using it on both my main sites since they introduced the new facilities towards the backend of last year and it seems pretty good. My sites are faster, I get some analytics and they have blocked a number of potential attacks. Their are paid tiers that give you more control as well. You could use both if you wanted to.

Comment: I noticed the other day actually, that stack overflow (and its sister sites obviously) are running through CloudFlare.

Comment: Yes, many big sites use them to offload a lot of caching.

Comment: Looking over Cloudflare, the WAF was not included in the free plan and $20 a month didn't seem to stack up against Atomicorps $99 / year.

Comment: I don't think you necessarily need the paid tier, you still get standard protection with the free tier. Combine with mod_security and one of the free rulesets & you have a decent level of protection. Or even just some basic IPTABLES rules and perhaps fail2ban.

Comment: Strange that OWASP is not included in CloudFlare's Free plan, seeing as OWASP is free! Not overly convinced of the free offerings tbh - seems more trouble than it's worth. And $20 per month + $5 a site per month is just way over the top... Does anyone have experience with CloudFlare free?

Comment: Yes, I'm only using the free version. Improved performance, some good stats and several attacks thwarted. and it really didn't take long to set up. Very easy. I have it on two domains.

Comment: I've been researching cloudflare a little more. I contacted them and on the free plan, you have to use their SSL certs. Only on paid plans can you use your own certs. Their free certs are shared and it seems that only the connection too CloudFlare is encrypted (http://serverfault.com/questions/505451/how-secure-is-cloudflares-basic-ssl) not the connection between cloudflare and your server! So a user will see an https connection, but the data from CF to your site is sent in the clear! And CF will only forward to port 80 on free accounts so... Nope! That's a deal breaker!